# put brackets around the year in a citation call-out

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am a beginner in Latex and I tried to put brackets around the year in the reference but I don't know what is wrong with my code all the incite references appear with numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\graphicspath{{./plots/}}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}
```

and the reference in bib file looks like

```
@article{tsay1984regression,
  title={Regression models with time series errors},
  author={Tsay, Ruey S},
  journal={Journal of the American Statistical Association},
  volume={79},
  number={385},
  pages={118--124},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis Group}
}
```

I want it looks like `Tsay(1984)`.

May someone help me an tell me what's wrong with my code

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable and show us how you cite the bib entry. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What do you get as output when you write \cite{tsay1984regression} in the text?

Comment: @Rik, or event better `\citet{tsay1984regression}`.

Comment: `\citeyear` or `\citeyearpar` are the two commands which inbuilt with `natbib` package to get the year alone...

Comment: you should use a natbib compatible bibliography style, e.g. plainnat.

Comment: You should never, ever load the citation management packages `apacite` and `natbib` in one and the same document.